# Extended Inline Assembly:Does the Destination operand is always "ebx" in "addl" instruction

Tags: assembly, att

When I use Extended Inline Assembly as this

```
int main(void)
{
    int result  = 2;
    int input  = 1;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("addl %2,%0":"=r"(result):"r"(result),"m"(input));
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

as expected,it will output "3".But the result is an uncertain number.
Then I objdump this file.
The result is

```
movl $0x2,0x1c(%esp)
movl $0x1,0x18(%esp)
mov 0x1c(%esp),%eax
add 0x18(%esp),%ebx
mov %ebx,0x1c(%esp)
```

In the 4th line,the destination operand is ebx rather than eax.The content of ebx is uncertain.
I want to ask,why the destination is ebx?
Is the ebx a default option in the addl instrution?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `("addl %2,%0" : "=r"(result) : "0"(result), "m"(input));`?

Comment: Yes,you are right.But the assembly code of the ("addl %2,%0" : "=r"(result) : "0"(result), "m"(input))  is